# Codeception onbeforeunload ajax request cause timeout

Tags: javascript, ajax, timeout, phantomjs, codeception

I have a problem that can be solve only with `window.onbeforeunload` event using the ajax request:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'SOME_URL', false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send('some=data');
};
```

It working in the browser well but it dosen't work with the *Codeception* Webdriver using *phantomjs*. I'm getting:

> [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException] Curl error
>   thrown for http POST to
>   /session/xxxyyyzzz/url with params:
>   {"url":"http://myhost.pl/someuri"}
>
> Operation timed out after 120001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

I've already extend timeout to 120 sec (from 30).

It work when I make request **sync** but it fails with **async** requests.

It looks like the *phantomjs* browser kills this request while getting out of the current page and this request blocks all the others.

Has anybody meets such a problem and have any ideas/solution?

Comment: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14396

Comment: Yes. This is exacly the problem that I'm forcing with. Unfortunattely it's still unresolved. Thank you!